# Mailjet: alert on undelivered recipients

Tags: email, mailjet, email-delivery

I'm aware this may not be the right place to ask this, but I don't know where else and others may encounter the same issue.

I'd like to have an aggregated view (or an alert) when some recipients in my contact list don't receive any of the emails my app sents. Is this possible?

I checked on the [*alert thing* in the docs](https://support.mailjet.tech/hc/en-us/articles/360042953053-Real-Time-Monitoring#rtm-overview-alerts) but it doesn't seem to do what I need. Although this seems like a pretty common need and there may not be necessary to setup webhooks and own app logic to handle this, wouldn't it?

Thanks

Comment: What does "receive" mean in your context. Do you mean the receiving mail server or the receivers mail client load or even open the email?

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced same issue with cPanel and many other providers like Mailchimp. This usually happens due to Empty Subject due to which Cross-Server Contacts may not happen. Also, if you are using PHPmail() or sendmail function instead of SMTP, You need to be using TLS1.2 or TLS1.3 though 1.0 is also supported but many of my E-mails were not delivered so I upgraded to TLS 1.3 . Also, Check if your mail goes to Spam Folder. In that case, increase your Website and Domain Score and Try to rank in Google Safe Browsing. Also, this also happens due to misleading Hosting Provider whose SMTP servers are not setup correctly or Provider send many spam messages due to which, you domain score may got low. I currently use interserver_smtp and cloudmate_smtp collectively for all my clients as interserver deliverablility in India is low and cloudmate works in both texas and india correctly. Try cPanel or Plesk as it has the best deliverability. One More thing, This could also be an issue of DNS. Check your DNS settings if MX records are pointed to MailJet Servers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I expected something at the Mailjet software level as they are available to send status of delivered mails, I reckon they should be able to aggregate those. I may not have asked the question at the right place though.